# What is the significance of the Kangaroo in Flash Forward (TV series)?

Tags: tv, flash-forward

I think I am one of three people that was disappointed that Flash Forward did not get a second season.  It was not a bad show, and certainly better than a lot of shows that did get past the first season.

Of the many disappointments that I suffered, the most pressing was the mystery of the kangaroo.  A kangaroo appears in both the first and last episodes, and the reason behind it was never explained in the show.

Is there any official word on what the deal with the kangaroo was?  Was is something from the original novel, or was it exclusive to the TV show that the creators just never got a chance to explain?

Comment: It definitely was not "a thing" in the original novel.  There may have been some characters in Australia (I don't remember) but there wasn't any kangaroo with great significance to the plot.  Then again, from what I recall of the TV series, there wasn't really a lot in common with the book apart from the basic premise.

Comment: That certainly solves one of my questions.  Incidentally, would you recommend the book?  I really like the premise, and if the book executes the premise in a way that is superior to the series then I need it in my life.

Comment: I definitely think the book is superior to the TV series and I would recommend it, although to be fair to the TV series, it may have gotten better if it had run longer than one season. It certainly had a top-notch cast. (I find Robert J Sawyer to be an entertaining popcorn sci-fi author in general - and Canadian, to boot!  Not super-hard sci-fi, but also not *too far-fetched.*  Nice middle ground.)